# How to stop audio from playing in flutter

Tags: flutter, audio

My code is meant to play a song when the user presses play sound and I need a button to stop the music from playing. I chose to play the music like this because the audio cache function was not working in my code for some reason (I kept getting an error saying my file couldn't be loaded) though this method works I have no idea on how to stop the music from playing like this.

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'dart:io';

class bodyscan extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _bodyscanState createState() => _bodyscanState();
}

enum PlayerState {stopped,playing,paused}

class _bodyscanState extends State<bodyscan> {

  String mp3Uri = "";
  void _playsound(){
    AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();
    player.play(mp3Uri);

  }

  void _loadsound() async {
    final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load("audio/doomed.m4a");
    Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    File tempFile = File('${tempDir.path}/doomed.m4a');
    await tempFile.writeAsBytes(data.buffer.asUint8List(), flush:true);
    mp3Uri = tempFile.uri.toString();
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    _loadsound();
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[

              InkWell(
                enableFeedback: false,
                child :Container (
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Text('PlaySound', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),) ,

                ),
                onTap: _playsound,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried simply `player.stop()`?

If it doesn't work, then maybe you should try to move AudioPlayer outside from 'playMusic' method, like this:

```
    AudioPlayer player = new AudioPlayer();
    String mp3Uri = "";

    void _playSound() {
      player.play(mp3Uri);
    }

    void _stopSound() {
      player.stop();
    }
```

Comment: I'm using AudioCache for playing files in local assets folder. audioCache.play() method is there but audioCache.stop() is not there. How to stop song using audioCache ??

Comment: @KPradeepKumarReddy try to assign audioCache variable player to null. Or simply create an AudioPlayer for this AudioCache and use it for control.

Comment: Thanks. I'm creating audio player instance for the audio cache and using it for control.  Can we know if the player is currently running ??  i'm not able to find any method like audioPlayer.isPlaying().  I want to check if the player is already running then don't play it again. How to achieve this functionality ?

Comment: @KPradeepKumarReddy I don't quite remember, but it seems you can use AudioCache for this and check if it's null or not

Answer (score 3):

If using [AudioCache](https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayers/blob/master/doc/audio_cache.md) for playing audio file from assets, here is a solution i found:

- create a AudioPlayer
- use it in your AudioCache Instance as a fixedPlayer
- you can then use stop() method on the AudioPlayer Instance

```
const timerFinishedAudio = "alarm-sound.mp3";
const audioFilesPrefix = 'audio/';
final audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();

// in your State
static AudioCache player = new AudioCache(prefix: audioFilesPrefix, fixedPlayer: audioPlayer);

// in a function
player.play(timerFinishedAudio);

// in another function or dispose()
audioPlayer.stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if there is method to stop the audio from the below method

```
_audioPlayer.stop();
```

Just check out this example created by the Audioplayers plugin :

https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayers/tree/master/example/lib

You can use the inkwell below where onTap you can use this stop method.